# How to make highcharts funnel into pyramid

Tags: highcharts

I have a client that needs a pyramid chart.   The funnel chart is perfect if only I could flip it around so it becomes a pyramid.

Seems like there would be a way to flip it but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just modify the `neckWidth` and `neckHeight` and make the total `width` 0?

```
        neckWidth: '100%',
        neckHeight: '0%',
        width: '0%'
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/sjjmw/).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want flip the Funnel chart you can use **reversed** attribute

in the series section of the chart

[Funnel reveresed](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.funnel.reversed)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using funnel chart you can use, area chart or stacked area chart.

```
type: 'area'
```

that will be an easier way to get pyramid like in here http://jsfiddle.net/KQ344/

hope this will help you in getting what you want.